# Create sequences from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df. Now I would like to create sequences of the following format:
the next x rows 
the row itself
the previous row

Lets say we have a df with only one col, each row containing the values 0 to 10 and x = 3.
Now we take the row containing 4 for example. Here we have:
the next 3 rows: 5, 6, 7
the row itself: 4
the previous row: 3
our sequence is: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

For making sequences containing the next rows I have this code:

```
sequential_data = []
prev_rates = deque(maxlen=SAMPLE_SIZE)
for i in df.values:
    prev_rates.append([n for n in i[:-1]])
    if len(prev_rates) == SAMPLE_SIZE:
        sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_rates), i[-1]])
```

But how can I add the previous row to each sequence?

Edit: another example:
[image]

Lets take x = 2 here:
As result we get:

```
[
  [nothing, because there is no previous row]
  [[0, 9], [1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6]]
  [[1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
  [[2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 4]]
  [[3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 4], [6, 3]]
  [[4, 5], [5, 4], [6, 3], [7, 2]]
  [[5, 4], [6, 3], [7, 2], [8, 1]]
  [[6, 3], [7, 2], [8, 1], [9, 0]]
  [nothing, because there are not 2 next rows (only 1)]
  [nothing, because there are no next rows]
]
```

(And of course the rows containing 'nothing,... ' should not be in the result

Comment: It sounds an awful lot like you want to use [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score -1):

Consider that, at index `k`, the slice of `df` consisting of `df.iloc[k-1:k+x]` is equivalent to reindexing and sequencing/slicing as `df.iloc[k:k+x+1]`. Then, just use

```
df.rolling(SAMPLE_SIZE+1)
```

as your sequence generator, and operate on those sequences.

Comment: I don't really get how to proceed then or how to access the created sequences. Since I am new in this whole topic, I am also not sure if I really made clear what I want. For this case I added another example to show what my result should be

Comment: This seems to be a hint rather an answer!

Answer (score -2):

```py
def generate_sequence(sequence1, sequence2, sequence3):
    new_sequence = []

    # Генерираме втората поредица
    for i in range(len(sequence1)):
        if i == 0:
            new_sequence.append(sequence1[i])
        else:
            new_sequence.append(sequence1[i] + sequence2[i - 1])

    # Генерираме третата поредица
    for i in range(len(sequence2)):
        if i == 0:
            new_sequence.append(sequence1[i] + sequence2[i])
        else:
            new_sequence.append(sequence2[i] - sequence2[i - 1])

    # Генерираме четвъртата поредица
    for i in range(len(sequence3)):
        if i == 0:
            new_sequence.append(sequence2[i] + sequence3[i])
        else:
            new_sequence.append(sequence3[i] + sequence3[i - 1])

    return new_sequence

# Първата поредица
sequence1 = [12, 14, 21, 22, 37, 46]

# Втората поредица
sequence2 = [34, 29, 33, 13, 2]

# Третата поредица
sequence3 = [11, 3, 27, 1, 14]

# Генериране на новата поредица
new_sequence = generate_sequence(sequence1, sequence2, sequence3)

# Отпечатване на новата поредица
print(new_sequence)
```